# Why does su ask for a password if stdin is redirected? How do I avoid this?

Tags: io-redirection, su, stdin

I'm using `su` (not interested in `sudo` for the purposes of this question) and observing the following behavior:

```
$ su USER -s /bin/bash -c "echo hi"
hi
$ printf "" | su USER -s /bin/bash -c "echo hi"
Password: su: Authentication failure
$ su USER -s /bin/bash -c "echo hi" < /dev/null
Password: su: Authentication failure
$ su USER -s /bin/bash -c "echo hi" < /dev/tty
Password:
$ su USER -s /bin/bash -c "echo hi" < /dev/tty1
hi
```

For the life of me I don't understand why the redirection of stdin causes a password prompt to come up. I'm using `su` in a context where stdin is already redirected, so I can't avoid this.

What is the reason for this, and how do I avoid the prompt in `su` when stdin is redirected?

Comment: how are you able to have `su` **not** asking password from non-root user in first place ? USER has no password ?

Comment: @Archemar: Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify, OP commented that the account USER has no password set.

From [`man pam_unix`](https://manpages.debian.org/libpam-modules/pam_unix.8) (*pam_unix* is the module referenced below):

> **nullok**
>
> The default action of this module is to not permit the user access to
>   a service if their official password is blank. The nullok argument
>   overrides this default and allows any user with a blank password to
>   access the service.
>
> **nullok_secure**
>
> The default action of this module is to not permit the user access to
>   a service if their official password is blank. The nullok_secure
>   argument overrides this default and allows any user with a blank
>   password to access the service as long as the value of PAM_TTY is set
>   to one of the values found in /etc/securetty.

I guess your PAM settings are using `nullok_secure`. That's the case on Debian 10.

Just replace `nullok_secure` with `nullok` to have it work. On Debian this would be `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, different Unixes or Linux distributions might put it elsewhere (eg in a specific file for `su`)

Additional note: for the command to ever succeed without password when using `nullok_secure`, it requires being run on a TTY present in `/etc/securetty` *or* the absence of `/etc/securetty` (which makes the statement "PAM_TTY is set to one of the values found in /etc/securetty" always true). Without TTY, this will not matter and will always fail.

Comment: Would you say this is a bug? Considering that when the password is empty, the caller could just redirect `</dev/tty1` and make the check useless?

Comment: What I'm not understanding is, isn't it trivial to bypass this "security" check? An attacker can just try every `/dev/ttyN` as stdin, and whichever one goes for the current user through would bypass the check that stdin is a "secure" TTY. Something seems wrong here, right?

Comment: But yes, if the attacker without tty (eg process backdoor/exploit) using the *same* account of an user *already logged* locally on a /dev/ttyX then using `< /dev/ttyX` will work. Eg: `ssh -T initialuser@targethost 'su USER -s /bin/bash -c "echo hi" < /dev/tty1'` , while `initialuser` is logged on `/dev/tty1` will print `hi`, if not logged, this will print `/dev/tty1: Permission denied` instead, because the login methods change the ownership of `/dev/tty1`.

Comment: Right, but then that means the check is buggy, right? Shouldn't `su` check to see whether it is run *under* a secure TTY, rather than merely check whether its *stdin* is a secure TTY? And moreover, if the current behavior is somehow indeed desirable (which I don't think is the case), then shouldn't the check instead be "is this user logged in on *any* secure TTY" (given otherwise it's just annoying me to no security benefit)?

Comment: I don't see any bug nor any security issue. Of course the use of a passwordless account, and lowering security to `nullok` are both security issues.

Comment: If the user is logged into a TTY, then that suddenly enables a remote attacker to use their `/dev/ttyN` via redirection to bypass this "security" check, right? Presumably that's not desired, and hence is a bug?

Comment: I don't know sorry